# Remove spacial character from string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

I am working in PHP, I have input like `123->`. I have tried to remove it by

`$string  = '123->';
preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string);`

BUT Failed. Any possible solution please

NOTE: The arrow is not typed by keyboard, this arrow is printed by PDF created tools, which auto include this arrow in file. I mean this is different from keyboard typed arrow as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Hmm since the arrow is added by PDF it might be easier to match instead of replace.

Comment: i have tried this one also, BUT afaqa ni hua :P